# Handling Stale Data in Prometheus Gauges

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus

Context: I want to build my own exporter for RabbitMQ. For that I've set an HTTP server that queries the management API, parses the response and builds the appropriate response with Prometheus format

I'm measuring number of messages in a queue to get alerted when a queue has too many messages in it. For that, i've set up the following gauge:
`rabbitmq_queue_messages{queue_name="Q1"}`

My question is: what happens if a queue gets deleted? for example:

1. at T1 the exporter returns rabbitmq_queue_messages{queue_name="Q1"} 5
2. at T2 the queue is being deleted for some reason
3. at T3 my exporter is being asked for the metrics again.

As I understand, at T3, even though the queue doesn't exist anymore, it will return the same `rabbitmq_queue_messages{queue_name="Q1"} 5` response since this is how gauges work on Prometheus. For me it seems odd because at T3, Q1 doesn't exist anymore so I'd expect to stop receiving data points for this queue, instead of receiving stale data.

The workaround I found for this is to build a new prometheus registry on each request to the exporter to start with a clean sheet, but it seems a bit hacky and I really don't feel comfortable working this way.

So, how can I avoid having stale gauge data in a more Prometheus idiomatic way?

Comment: Which client library are you using? I.e. what language is your exporter written in?

Comment: this one https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby

Comment: Setting it to 0 is not an option?

Comment: so I have to go through all the label combinations and make them zero? of course I can do it but again it sounds a bit hacky

Answer (score 2):

If this is a Java exporter, written using [`client_java`](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java), you can simply clear your `Gauge` (in `myGauge.clear()`) instead of building a whole new `Registry`.

Or, if that is too heavy-weight and you have a way to get notified when a queue is deleted, just call `Gauge.remove(queueName)` when you get the notification.

**Edit:** Never actually seen any Ruby code before, but it would seem that [`Registry.unregister("rabbitmq_queue_messages")`](https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby/blob/367cbff320bf688da856ebfda3e85aed6fe937bd/lib/prometheus/client/registry.rb#L34) might be the less heavy-handed way of clearing just the one metric (with all its label combinations, i.e. in your case for all queues). I don't see anything similar to the Java client's `Gauge.remove()` that would allow removing just one sample/label combination, but I might be missing something.